# PDF Bookmarks in classicthesis Template

Tags: hyperref, classicthesis, bookmarks

I am using the *classicthesis* style and thesis template from [André Miede's Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home).

The PDF bookmarks for the bibliography, declaration and colophon are subordinate to the PDF bookmark for the 'Appendix' part.

I do not want the bibliography, declaration and colophon to be under any superordinate bookmark. Instead, I would like each of them to be bookmarked separately as with–and also at the same level of–the dedication, abstract, ToC etc.

One of the style's maintainers suggested a [workaround](https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/issues/161/back-matter-pdf-bookmarks); however, it is not exactly what I am trying to achieve.

I have not included an MWE as I am using the unmodified template.